# How to iterate over a matrix only taking the diagonal values and change them python without np

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

I have a "square" Matrix (the number of columns = number of rows):

like:

```
m = [[10,11,12],
 [13,14,15],
 [16,17,18]]
```

I need an iteration that takes the values: m[0][0], m[1][1] and m[2][2] and adds 1 to the number so it returns:

```
m = [[11,11,12],
 [13,15,15],
 [16,17,19]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `m` is a square we can simply iterate across the list and increment the ith element of each list by one:

```
m = [[10,11,12],
 [13,14,15],
 [16,17,18]]

for i, lst in enumerate(m):
    lst[i] += 1 

print(*m, sep='\n')
```

Outputs:

```
[11, 11, 12]
[13, 15, 15]
[16, 17, 19]
```